# Using a BuildContext when receiving a FlutterFire push notification

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

In order to do download and save a `File` on the native side of the app when receiving a push notification, we need to have a `BuildContext` when receiving it from FlutterFire.

But as the FlutterFire background push notifications handler run on an isolate, we don't know where to find a valid `BuildContext`.

Comment: Hi @Roc Boronat, did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but for me, I fixed it by defining a global variable like below:

```
BuildContext globalContext;

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.data}");
    Provider.of<HomePageSearchFlag>(globalContext, listen: false)
        .changeStatus(searchStatus: true);
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    globalContext = context;
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      setupFCM(context);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh my! I'll try :·)

Comment: Hum, it doesn't work. It seems the `initState()` of my app is not being run when receiving a push notification while in the background. Why does yours run?

Comment: I think you need to use background processing:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes

Comment: Hum... It doesn't seem that link explains how to get a Flutter context in a new isolate. I'm starting to think that's not possible :sad: